# CentOS 7.2 system abnormal restart

Tags: linux, centos, kernel-panic

Have you ever had any of the following problems？
Our environment is CentOS 7.2. Running Java applications, sometimes the system will restart inexplicably. The screenshot of error reporting is as follows. Please help me.

---

```
[BEGIN] 2019/10/19 12:09:34
       STATE: TASK_RUNNING (PANIC)
crash> exit
[root@test ~]# crash /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/vmlinux /home/vmcore

crash 7.1.5-2.el7
Copyright (C) 2002-2016  Red Hat, Inc.
Copyright (C) 2004, 2005, 2006, 2010  IBM Corporation
Copyright (C) 1999-2006  Hewlett-Packard Co
Copyright (C) 2005, 2006, 2011, 2012  Fujitsu Limited
Copyright (C) 2006, 2007  VA Linux Systems Japan K.K.
Copyright (C) 2005, 2011  NEC Corporation
Copyright (C) 1999, 2002, 2007  Silicon Graphics, Inc.
Copyright (C) 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002  Mission Critical Linux, Inc.
This program is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License,
and you are welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under
certain conditions.  Enter "help copying" to see the conditions.
This program has absolutely no warranty.  Enter "help warranty" for details.

GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"...

      KERNEL: /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/vmlinux
    DUMPFILE: /home/vmcore  [PARTIAL DUMP]
        CPUS: 4
        DATE: Fri Oct 18 14:59:51 2019
      UPTIME: 129 days, 17:06:58
LOAD AVERAGE: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
       TASKS: 1011
    NODENAME: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
     RELEASE: 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
     VERSION: #1 SMP Thu Nov 19 22:10:57 UTC 2015
     MACHINE: x86_64  (2194 Mhz)
      MEMORY: 8 GB
       PANIC: "BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000008"
         PID: 122524
     COMMAND: "java"
        TASK: ffff88006e51f300  [THREAD_INFO: ffff8800bb150000]
         CPU: 0
       STATE: TASK_RUNNING (PANIC)

crash> 
crash> 
crash> 
crash> bt
PID: 122524  TASK: ffff88006e51f300  CPU: 0   COMMAND: "java"
 #0 [ffff8800bb1538f0] machine_kexec at ffffffff81051beb
 #1 [ffff8800bb153950] crash_kexec at ffffffff810f2542
 #2 [ffff8800bb153a20] oops_end at ffffffff8163e1a8
 #3 [ffff8800bb153a48] no_context at ffffffff8162e2b8
 #4 [ffff8800bb153a98] __bad_area_nosemaphore at ffffffff8162e34e
 #5 [ffff8800bb153ae0] bad_area at ffffffff8162e6c7
 #6 [ffff8800bb153b08] __do_page_fault at ffffffff81641035
 #7 [ffff8800bb153b60] trace_do_page_fault at ffffffff816411b3
 #8 [ffff8800bb153b98] do_async_page_fault at ffffffff816408d9
 #9 [ffff8800bb153bb0] async_page_fault at ffffffff8163d438
    [exception RIP: tcp_sendmsg+261]
    RIP: ffffffff81576a15  RSP: ffff8800bb153c68  RFLAGS: 00010246
    RAX: 0000000000000000  RBX: ffff8800bb153da8  RCX: ffff8800bb153fd8
    RDX: 00000000fffffefd  RSI: 0000000000000000  RDI: ffff8802302bcb70
    RBP: ffff8800bb153d20   R8: 0000000000000000   R9: 0000000000000001
    R10: ffff8800bb153da8  R11: 0000000000000293  R12: 00000000000000ef
    R13: ffff8802302bcb00  R14: ffff8800bb153e28  R15: ffff880104d46400
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff  CS: 0010  SS: 0018
#10 [ffff8800bb153d28] inet_sendmsg at ffffffff815a0f44
#11 [ffff8800bb153d58] sock_aio_write at ffffffff8150fe47
#12 [ffff8800bb153e20] do_sync_write at ffffffff811dddad
#13 [ffff8800bb153ef8] vfs_write at ffffffff811de6c5
#14 [ffff8800bb153f38] sys_write at ffffffff811df06f
#15 [ffff8800bb153f80] system_call_fastpath at ffffffff81645909
    RIP: 00007fe29b4336ad  RSP: 00007fe198f1f220  RFLAGS: 00000246
    RAX: 0000000000000001  RBX: ffffffff81645909  RCX: 000000007fffffff
    RDX: 00000000000000ef  RSI: 00007fe278130d40  RDI: 00000000000001e1
    RBP: 00007fe198f1f2d0   R8: 00000000000000ef   R9: 00000006d421efa0
    R10: 0000000000002370  R11: 0000000000000293  R12: 00007fe198f1f310
    R13: 00000000000000ef  R14: 00007fe1d041c3b8  R15: 00007fe278130d40
    ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000001  CS: 0033  SS: 002b
crash> 
crash> 
crash> 
crash> kmem -i
                 PAGES        TOTAL      PERCENTAGE
    TOTAL MEM  1997872       7.6 GB         ----
         FREE    39523     154.4 MB    1% of TOTAL MEM
         USED  1958349       7.5 GB   98% of TOTAL MEM
       SHARED   601413       2.3 GB   30% of TOTAL MEM
      BUFFERS        0            0    0% of TOTAL MEM
       CACHED   718444       2.7 GB   35% of TOTAL MEM
         SLAB    54483     212.8 MB    2% of TOTAL MEM

   TOTAL SWAP  2097151         8 GB         ----
    SWAP USED      764         3 MB    0% of TOTAL SWAP
    SWAP FREE  2096387         8 GB   99% of TOTAL SWAP

 COMMIT LIMIT  3096087      11.8 GB         ----
    COMMITTED  1466361       5.6 GB   47% of TOTAL LIMIT
crash> 
crash> ps
   PID    PPID  CPU       TASK        ST  %MEM     VSZ    RSS  COMM
      0      0   0  ffffffff81951440  RU   0.0       0      0  [swapper/0]
>     0      0   1  ffff880232590000  RU   0.0       0      0  [swapper/1]
>     0      0   2  ffff880232590b80  RU   0.0       0      0  [swapper/2]
>     0      0   3  ffff880232591700  RU   0.0       0      0  [swapper/3]
      1      0   1  ffff880232d78000  IN   0.0  188780   3292  systemd
      2      0   0  ffff880232d78b80  IN   0.0       0      0  [kthreadd]
      3      2   0  ffff880232d79700  IN   0.0       0      0  [ksoftirqd/0]
      7      2   0  ffff880232d7c500  IN   0.0       0      0  [migration/0]
      8      2   0  ffff880232d7d080  IN   0.0       0      0  [rcu_bh]
      9      2   0  ffff880232d7dc00  IN   0.0       0      0  [rcuob/0]
    169      2   0  ffff8802329f2280  IN   0.0       0      0  [rcu_sched]
    170      2   0  ffff8802329f2e00  IN   0.0       0      0  [rcuos/0]
    329      2   0  ffff880232566780  IN   0.0       0      0  [rcuos/159]
    330      2   0  ffff880232567300  IN   0.0       0      0  [watchdog/0]
    331      2   1  ffff88023213b980  IN   0.0       0      0  [watchdog/1]
    332      2   1  ffff88023213c500  IN   0.0       0      0  [migration/1]
    333      2   1  ffff88023213d080  IN   0.0       0      0  [ksoftirqd/1]
    336      2   2  ffff88023213f300  IN   0.0       0      0  [watchdog/2]
    337      2   2  ffff880232170000  IN   0.0       0      0  [migration/2]
    338      2   2  ffff880232170b80  IN   0.0       0      0  [ksoftirqd/2]
    340      2   2  ffff880232172280  IN   0.0       0      0  [kworker/2:0H]
    341      2   3  ffff880232172e00  IN   0.0       0      0  [watchdog/3]
    342      2   3  ffff880232173980  IN   0.0       0      0  [migration/3]
    343      2   3  ffff880232174500  IN   0.0       0      0  [ksoftirqd/3]
    345      2   3  ffff880232175c00  IN   0.0       0      0  [kworker/3:0H]
    346      2   1  ffff880232176780  IN   0.0       0      0  [khelper]
    347      2   3  ffff880232177300  IN   0.0       0      0  [kdevtmpfs]
    348      2   1  ffff8802322b0000  IN   0.0       0      0  [netns]
    349      2   1  ffff8802322b0b80  IN   0.0       0      0  [perf]
    350      2   1  ffff8802322b1700  IN   0.0       0      0  [writeback]
    351      2   1  ffff8802322b2280  IN   0.0       0      0  [kintegrityd]
    352      2   1  ffff8802322b2e00  IN   0.0       0      0  [bioset]
    353      2   1  ffff8802322b3980  IN   0.0       0      0  [kblockd]
    354      2   1  ffff8802322b4500  IN   0.0       0      0  [md]
    360      2   0  ffff880231fd8b80  IN   0.0       0      0  [khungtaskd]
    361      2   0  ffff880231fd9700  IN   0.0       0      0  [kswapd0]
    362      2   1  ffff880231fda280  IN   0.0       0      0  [ksmd]
    363      2   1  ffff880231fdae00  IN   0.0       0      0  [khugepaged]
    364      2   2  ffff880231fdb980  IN   0.0       0      0  [fsnotify_mark]
    365      2   1  ffff880231fdc500  IN   0.0       0      0  [crypto]
    373      2   1  ffff88022e731700  IN   0.0       0      0  [kthrotld]
    375      2   1  ffff88022e732e00  IN   0.0       0      0  [kmpath_rdacd]
    376      2   1  ffff88022e733980  IN   0.0       0      0  [kpsmoused]
    395      2   1  ffff88022e0fb980  IN   0.0       0      0  [deferwq]
    428      2   1  ffff88022e0f8b80  IN   0.0       0      0  [kauditd]
    596      2   2  ffff88022e111700  IN   0.0       0      0  [ata_sff]
    598      2   0  ffff88022e115c00  IN   0.0       0      0  [scsi_eh_0]
    599      2   2  ffff88022e112280  IN   0.0       0      0  [scsi_tmf_0]
    600      2   1  ffff880036a8ae00  IN   0.0       0      0  [events_power_ef]
    605      2   1  ffff88022da78000  IN   0.0       0      0  [scsi_eh_1]
    608      2   1  ffff88022da79700  IN   0.0       0      0  [scsi_tmf_1]
    620      2   2  ffff88022da7dc00  IN   0.0       0      0  [ttm_swap]
    621      2   3  ffff88022e324500  IN   0.0       0      0  [virtscsi-scan]
    622      2   2  ffff88022e322e00  IN   0.0       0      0  [scsi_eh_2]
    625      2   3  ffff88022e320000  IN   0.0       0      0  [scsi_tmf_2]
    690      2   0  ffff88022e325c00  IN   0.0       0      0  [kdmflush]
    691      2   0  ffff88022e326780  IN   0.0       0      0  [bioset]
    698      2   0  ffff88022e327300  IN   0.0       0      0  [kdmflush]
    699      2   0  ffff88022e321700  IN   0.0       0      0  [bioset]
    716      2   1  ffff88022da7b980  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfsalloc]
    717      2   1  ffff88022da7c500  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfs_mru_cache]
    718      2   1  ffff88022da7f300  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfs-buf/dm-1]
    719      2   1  ffff88022da7d080  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfs-data/dm-1]
    720      2   1  ffff88022da7e780  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfs-conv/dm-1]
    721      2   1  ffff88022cf18000  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfs-cil/dm-1]
    722      2   1  ffff88022cf18b80  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfsaild/dm-1]
    793      1   0  ffff880036895c00  IN   0.4   78188  40640  systemd-journal
    822      1   2  ffff88022e38a280  IN   0.0  200764   1124  lvmetad
    823      1   3  ffff88022e38c500  IN   0.0   43552   1040  systemd-udevd
    824      2   2  ffff88022cf1ae00  IN   0.0       0      0  [rpciod]
    849      2   1  ffff88022cf1dc00  IN   0.0       0      0  [vballoon]
    863      2   3  ffff88022cf1e780  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfs-buf/vda1]
    864      2   1  ffff88022cf19700  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfs-data/vda1]
    865      2   1  ffff88022cf1c500  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfs-conv/vda1]
    866      2   0  ffff88022ce9a280  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfs-cil/vda1]
    868      2   3  ffff88022ce98b80  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfsaild/vda1]
    881      2   1  ffff88022ce99700  IN   0.0       0      0  [kdmflush]
    882      2   1  ffff88022ce9d080  IN   0.0       0      0  [bioset]
    884      2   1  ffff88022ce9ae00  IN   0.0       0      0  [kdmflush]
    885      2   1  ffff88022ce9c500  IN   0.0       0      0  [bioset]
    891      2   1  ffff88022ce9b980  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfs-buf/dm-2]
    892      2   1  ffff8800bb500000  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfs-data/dm-2]
    893      2   1  ffff8800bb500b80  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfs-conv/dm-2]
    894      2   1  ffff8800bb501700  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfs-cil/dm-2]
    896      2   2  ffff8800bb502280  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfsaild/dm-2]
    901      2   1  ffff8800bb505080  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfs-buf/dm-3]
    902      2   1  ffff8800bb505c00  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfs-data/dm-3]
    903      2   1  ffff8800bb506780  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfs-conv/dm-3]
    904      2   1  ffff8800bb507300  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfs-cil/dm-3]
    905      2   1  ffff880230bd8000  IN   0.0       0      0  [xfsaild/dm-3]
    921      1   2  ffff88022e388b80  IN   0.0  114560   1588  auditd
    933      1   2  ffff88022e730b80  IN   0.0  114560   1588  auditd
    944      1   2  ffff88022e388000  IN   0.0   24340   1584  systemd-logind
    945      1   0  ffff88022e38d080  IN   0.0   21616   1024  qemu-ga
    947      1   2  ffff88022e389700  IN   0.0   24420   1416  dbus-daemon
    948      1   0  ffff880230bdd080  IN   0.0  195044    692  gssproxy
    949      1   1  ffff880230bd8b80  IN   0.0  195044    692  gssproxy
    950      1   1  ffff880230bde780  IN   0.0  195044    692  gssproxy
    951      1   1  ffff880230bd9700  IN   0.0  195044    692  gssproxy
    952      1   1  ffff880230bdae00  IN   0.0  195044    692  gssproxy
    953      1   1  ffff880230bdf300  IN   0.0  195044    692  gssproxy
    954      1   1  ffff88022e38b980  IN   0.0   19296    996  irqbalance
    957      1   1  ffff88022e38dc00  IN   0.2  689696  23020  rsyslogd
    979      1   0  ffff88022e735c00  IN   0.2  689696  23020  in:imjournal
    980      1   0  ffff88022e735080  IN   0.2  689696  23020  rs:main Q:Reg
   1157      1   1  ffff88022e333980  IN   0.0  103844   3864  sshd
   1164      1   0  ffff880230f0ae00  IN   0.0   24996    408  xinetd
   1188      1   0  ffff880230f08b80  IN   0.0   80660   1412  zabbix_agentd
   1197   1188   2  ffff88022f1f4500  IN   0.0   80660   1596  zabbix_agentd
   1198   1188   3  ffff88022f1f5c00  IN   0.0   80784   2384  zabbix_agentd
   1199   1188   3  ffff88022f1f3980  IN   0.0   80784   2384  zabbix_agentd
   1200   1188   3  ffff880231fdf300  IN   0.0   80784   2384  zabbix_agentd
   1201   1188   0  ffff880231fde780  IN   0.0   80792   2276  zabbix_agentd
   1207      1   3  ffff8800bb504500  IN   0.0  110048    756  agetty
   1326      1   1  ffff88022e113980  IN   0.0   89476   2092  master
   1332   1326   0  ffff880230bda280  IN   0.0   89648   3836  qmgr
   1352      1   1  ffff88022e332e00  IN   0.0  124192   1584  crond
   1353      1   3  ffff88022e115080  IN   0.0   25672   1820  ntpd
   1376      2   2  ffff88022e110b80  IN   0.0       0      0  [kworker/2:1H]
   1912      2   0  ffff880144a39700  IN   0.0       0      0  [kworker/0:2]
   2065      2   3  ffff88022e322280  IN   0.0       0      0  [kworker/3:1H]
  10484      2   1  ffff88014cf45c00  IN   0.0       0      0  [kworker/1:2H]
  10833      2   2  ffff88009e142e00  IN   0.0       0      0  [kworker/2:2]
  12810      1   3  ffff8800bb331700  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  12811      1   3  ffff8800bb336780  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  30122      2   2  ffff88022fb85080  IN   0.0       0      0  [kworker/u320:0]
  41953      2   3  ffff88006e411700  IN   0.0       0      0  [kworker/3:0]
  42462      2   2  ffff88014568ae00  IN   0.0       0      0  [kworker/u320:2]
  49529   1326   3  ffff88022ff47300  IN   0.0   89580   3940  pickup
  50458      1   1  ffff8800bb330000  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  51760      2   1  ffff88022c794500  IN   0.0       0      0  [kworker/1:1]
  53165      2   1  ffff88022c792e00  IN   0.0       0      0  [kworker/1:0H]
  54670      1   3  ffff8802303ce780  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  55240      1   1  ffff88009e387300  IN   0.0   64948   1084  rpcbind
  58290      1   3  ffff88014c99b980  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  58294      1   3  ffff88014c99e780  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  58613      2   0  ffff880036a8dc00  IN   0.0       0      0  [kworker/0:2H]
  59013      2   1  ffff8800bb330b80  IN   0.0       0      0  [kworker/1:0]
  59267      2   0  ffff8800bb1d5080  IN   0.0       0      0  [kworker/0:1]
  59424      2   2  ffff8800bb1d0000  IN   0.0       0      0  [kworker/2:0]
  59918      2   3  ffff8800bb1d2280  IN   0.0       0      0  [kworker/3:1]
  61398      1   3  ffff88013024b980  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  66543      2   0  ffff88014c99dc00  IN   0.0       0      0  [kworker/0:0H]
  87627      1   0  ffff880230634500  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  87628      1   1  ffff880230630b80  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  123411      1   3  ffff8800910fe780  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  123412      1   3  ffff880016043980  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  123436      1   0  ffff8800bb3ce780  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  123438      1   2  ffff8800bb3c8b80  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  123439      1   0  ffff880016042280  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  124242      1   0  ffff88006e415c00  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  124243      1   0  ffff88022c482280  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  124244      1   0  ffff88006e412e00  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  124728      1   1  ffff880016040000  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  125051      1   2  ffff88022da78b80  IN  46.4 9428784 4377788  java
  149731      1   2  ffff88009e10ae00  IN   2.8 4143428 265568  java
  149732      1   0  ffff88009e10d080  IN   2.8 4143428 265568  java
  149733      1   3  ffff88022e2c3980  IN   2.8 4143428 265568  java
  149734      1   3  ffff8802304ab980  IN   2.8 4143428 265568  java
  149735      1   3  ffff8802304a8000  IN   2.8 4143428 265568  java
  149736      1   1  ffff88022e116780  IN   2.8 4143428 265568  java
  149737      1   0  ffff88022e2c5080  IN   2.8 4143428 265568  java
  149738      1   0  ffff88009e143980  IN   2.8 4143428 265568  java
  149739      1   3  ffff88009e10a280  IN   2.8 4143428 265568  java
  149740      1   2  ffff88009e10b980  IN   2.8 4143428 265568  java
crash>   
crash> 
crash> bt
PID: 122524  TASK: ffff88006e51f300  CPU: 0   COMMAND: "java"
 #0 [ffff8800bb1538f0] machine_kexec at ffffffff81051beb
 #1 [ffff8800bb153950] crash_kexec at ffffffff810f2542
 #2 [ffff8800bb153a20] oops_end at ffffffff8163e1a8
 #3 [ffff8800bb153a48] no_context at ffffffff8162e2b8
 #4 [ffff8800bb153a98] __bad_area_nosemaphore at ffffffff8162e34e
 #5 [ffff8800bb153ae0] bad_area at ffffffff8162e6c7
 #6 [ffff8800bb153b08] __do_page_fault at ffffffff81641035
 #7 [ffff8800bb153b60] trace_do_page_fault at ffffffff816411b3
 #8 [ffff8800bb153b98] do_async_page_fault at ffffffff816408d9
 #9 [ffff8800bb153bb0] async_page_fault at ffffffff8163d438
    [exception RIP: tcp_sendmsg+261]
    RIP: ffffffff81576a15  RSP: ffff8800bb153c68  RFLAGS: 00010246
    RAX: 0000000000000000  RBX: ffff8800bb153da8  RCX: ffff8800bb153fd8
    RDX: 00000000fffffefd  RSI: 0000000000000000  RDI: ffff8802302bcb70
    RBP: ffff8800bb153d20   R8: 0000000000000000   R9: 0000000000000001
    R10: ffff8800bb153da8  R11: 0000000000000293  R12: 00000000000000ef
    R13: ffff8802302bcb00  R14: ffff8800bb153e28  R15: ffff880104d46400
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff  CS: 0010  SS: 0018
#10 [ffff8800bb153d28] inet_sendmsg at ffffffff815a0f44
#11 [ffff8800bb153d58] sock_aio_write at ffffffff8150fe47
#12 [ffff8800bb153e20] do_sync_write at ffffffff811dddad
#13 [ffff8800bb153ef8] vfs_write at ffffffff811de6c5
#14 [ffff8800bb153f38] sys_write at ffffffff811df06f
#15 [ffff8800bb153f80] system_call_fastpath at ffffffff81645909
    RIP: 00007fe29b4336ad  RSP: 00007fe198f1f220  RFLAGS: 00000246
    RAX: 0000000000000001  RBX: ffffffff81645909  RCX: 000000007fffffff
    RDX: 00000000000000ef  RSI: 00007fe278130d40  RDI: 00000000000001e1
    RBP: 00007fe198f1f2d0   R8: 00000000000000ef   R9: 00000006d421efa0
    R10: 0000000000002370  R11: 0000000000000293  R12: 00007fe198f1f310
    R13: 00000000000000ef  R14: 00007fe1d041c3b8  R15: 00007fe278130d40
    ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000001  CS: 0033  SS: 002b
crash> 
crash> dis -l tcp_sendmsg+261
/usr/src/debug/kernel-3.10.0-327.el7/linux-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/arch/x86/include/asm/bitops.h: 104
0xffffffff81576a15 <tcp_sendmsg+261>:   lock andb $0xfe,0x8(%rax)
crash> 
crash> exit
[END] 2019/10/19 14:28:41
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend updating to the latest CentOS 7.x kernel before spending any more effort troubleshooting this, if possible. This might be some old bug that was fixed at some time between November 2015 and now.

From the backtrace, it looks like the system is doing a filesystem write operation (`sys_write`, `vfs_write`) which requires network access for some reason (`inet_sendmsg`). Are you using NFS, or some other filesystem type that requires network access? Anyway, in `tcp_sendmsg` it turns out that some pointer had an uninitialized (null) value, which triggers an exception and a crash follows. Looking at `tcp_sendmsg()` in `net/ipv4/tcp.c`, one of the first things the function does is placing a lock on the socket, so it might be that the socket pointer was NULL.

Comment: Thank you very much！Which bug is triggered by this problem?